# Why do queries against this synonym return no records when queries against its referenced table do?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named `AP.AP_BATCHES_ALL`:

```
SELECT
  OWNER,
  OBJECT_NAME,
  OBJECT_TYPE
FROM
  ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE
  OWNER = 'AP' AND OBJECT_NAME = 'AP_BATCHES_ALL'
```

```
+-------+----------------+-------------+
| OWNER | OBJECT_NAME    | OBJECT_TYPE |
+-------+----------------+-------------+
| AP    | AP_BATCHES_ALL | TABLE       |
+-------+----------------+-------------+
```

I can query this table:

```
SELECT * FROM AP.AP_BATCHES_ALL
```

200,000+ records are returned.

Now, there is a synonym named `APPS.AP_BATCHES` that references the aforementioned `AP.AP_BATCHES_ALL` table:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_SYNONYMS WHERE OWNER = 'APPS' AND SYNONYM_NAME = 'AP_BATCHES'
```

```
+-------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------+
| OWNER | SYNONYM_NAME | TABLE_OWNER | TABLE_NAME     | DB_LINK |
+-------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------+
| APPS  | AP_BATCHES   | AP          | AP_BATCHES_ALL |         |
+-------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------+
```

Now, when I query `APPS.AP_BATCHES` (the synonym), I get *no* records:

```
SELECT * FROM APPS.AP_BATCHES
```

No records are returned, even though `APPS.AP_BATCHES` is merely a synonym for `AP.AP_BATCHES_ALL` (the table containing 200,000+ records).

Why aren't queries *against the synonym* returning records when queries *against the referenced table* do?

Comment: Are there any policies (DBMS_RLS, also see v$vpd_policies) on APPS.AP_BATCHES?

Comment: @Vincent: You read my mind. Turn that into an answer and I will give you credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I thought that you were running into a shadowing issue between a view and a public synonym. This is not the case here however, since APPS can only own one object named AP_BATCHES (the synonym).

Would there be, by any chance, row-level policies (`v$vpd_policies`) defined on this synonym?

By the way, I didn't know that (1) you could add policies to synonyms and (2) that the release 12 was using them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I understand that `APPS.AP_BATCHES` is usually a view *in Release 11*. However, I am working with Release 12, whereby the schema has undergone some surgery. I performed your query and the only object named `AP_BATCHES` is the `APPS.AP_BATCHES` synonym I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @adam: I should also have seen in your example that you have specified the owner (and APPS can't both own a view AND a synonym with the same name)

Comment: You are right, Release 12 is using Row Level Security on many of its synonyms (strange but true). A commonly used policy is named `ORG_SEC` (**org**anization **sec**urity?) and it introduces the following predicate: `1=2`. This effectively prevents the synonyms from retrieving records. Very, very strange.